# Plotting a line above/below existing lines created with plotyy

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm running this code:

```
t = linspace(0, 10, 1000);
y1 = 2*t;
y2 = 3*t;
figure;
[ax, h1, h2] = plotyy(t, y1, t, y2);
set(h1, 'LineWidth', 4);
set(h2, 'LineWidth', 4);
hold on;
h3 = plot([5, 5], [0, 3000], 'LineWidth', 6, 'Color', [0.6, 0.6, 0.6]);
```

Which creates this plot:

[image]

Notice how the vertical grey line appears on top of the blue line (y1) but below the green line (y2).

How do I plot the grey line either on top of the other two lines, or below the other two lines?

Comment: Seems like the `plotyy` adds a lot of complexity to this problem, I found this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/292321 and this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/311595, but no good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options:

A. Bring the gray line forward by moving it to the second axes created by the `plotyy` command

```
set(h3,'parent',ax(2));
```

B. Place the gray line on the bottom by rearranging the order of the blue and grey lines on 
the axes.

```
chld = [h1 h3];
set(ax(1),'children',chld); %# reorders the two lines so that the gray line is in back.
```

Answer (score 2):

To make the gray line bottom, you can also change the order of drawing.

```
t = linspace(0, 10, 1000);
y1 = 2*t;
y2 = 3*t;
figure;
h3 = plot([5, 5], [0, max(y1)], 'LineWidth', 6, 'Color', [0.6, 0.6, 0.6]);
hold on;
[ax, h1, h2] = plotyy(t, y1, t, y2);
set(h1, 'LineWidth', 4);
set(h2, 'LineWidth', 4);
```

There's a trick in `h3 = plot(...)` to make sure the left scale is correct, though.

[image]